# How to share a static variable between C++ source files?

Tags: c++, file, class, static, scope

I don't know if it is possible to do this, but I have tried several ways and nothing seems to work. Basically I need to access the same static member from several files which include the same class definition.

```
// Filename: S.h

class S {
public:
    static int foo;

    static void change(int new_foo) {
        foo = new_foo;
    }

};

int S::foo = 0;
```

Then in a class definition (other .cpp file) I have:

```
// Filename: A.h

#include "S.h"    

class A {
public:
    void do_something() {
        S::change(1);
    }
};
```

And in another file:

```
// Filename: program.cpp

#include "S.h"
#include "A.h"

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    A a = new A();
    S::change(2);        

    std::cout << S::foo << std::endl;

    a->do_something();

    std::cout << S::foo << std::endl;

}
```

Now, I would expect the second function call to change the S::foo to 1, but the output is still:

```
2
```

Is the A.h file creating a local copy of the static class?

Thank you
Tommaso

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line:

```
int S::foo = 0;
```

needs to be in exactly one source file, not in the header. So move it from `S.h` to `S.cpp`.

Comment: Which is to say it should not be in the header.

Comment: Great, thank you. I was just reading http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds2-4/ovp.html and found the same solution, but thanks anyway, you deserve the accepted answer :)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks in putting the methods code in the header?

Comment: If more than one source file includes that header (which is often the case) the variable will be defined twice, which depending on context can lead to anything from a compiler error to massively confusing bugs.

Comment: Some drawbacks for putting method code in headers: 1. Possibly longer compilation times. 2. Any needed `#includes` would need to be put in the header as well.

Comment: @tunnuz, also use guards to avoid multiple inclusion, your main program includes "s.h" twice.

Comment: Advantage to putting method in header: templates require it that way. Compilation time won't really be affected one way or the other. One convention is to turn `static` data members into static locals of static members in the header file. This also prevents issues with order of initialization.